# XSLT Select all siblings until specific nested

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'am trying to get all  nodes from the following sample table until the next td with a style attached using XSLT 1.0 (i can not use 2.0 here)

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="..."></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="..."></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Starting at the first /tbody/tr i used the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="following::td[not(attribute::style)]">
```

But then i got all td's except the one with the style attached.

Comment: Please show a complete input XML, your complete stylesheet and the output you expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all the following td elements whose *nearest* following td-with-style is the same as *my* nearest following td-with-style:

```
following::td[generate-id(following::td[@style][1]) = generate-id(current()/following::td[@style][1])]
```

This includes the case where `current()` is the last row with a `td[@style]`, in that case both the generate-id values will be the empty string.